# What are the different ways of performing sorting in java

Tags: java

This question was asked in an interview . Except Collections.sort() what are the other methods .

Comment: can you elaborate the question.

Comment: Do you mean, polymorphic overloads of `Collections.sort()`?

Comment: Is the term polymorphic appropriate for static methods? (I am not saying it isn't, I am asking)

Answer (score 7):

### Sorting Interfaces

[`Comparable<T>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) and [`Comparator<T>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) are the standard interfaces used by all standard Java sorting options (all except those on primitive arrays, that is).

In Java-speak, any Class that implements Comparable has a "natural order". (Technically, it must implement `Comparable<? super E>` where E matches itself, to have a natural order). Classes that don't have a natural order can be sorted using an external Comparator. A Comparator can also be used to implement a sort order that runs against the natural order (e.g. sort Strings in descending alphabetic order).

These principles are applied both in the [`SortedSet<E>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) and [`SortedMap<K,V>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) implementations, that sort their elements / keys automatically using either the natural order or a supplied comparator.

These same principles can also be found in the static Utility methods

- [`Arrays.sort(arr)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29) and
  [`Arrays.sort(arr, comparator)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5b%5d,%20java.util.Comparator%29) for Arrays
- [`Collections.sort(list)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) and [`Collections.sort(list, comparator)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) for Lists

that can be used to sort arrays and lists, respectively, each of which don't support sorting themselves.

---

### Guava

[The Guava Library](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) takes this a bit further by providing the abstract [`Ordering`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html) class as base implementation of `Comparator` which already contains standard methods like providing a reverse view of itself and many convenience methods for sorting and retrieving based on this `Ordering`.

---

### Reference

A good article about [Object Ordering](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html) can be found in the Sun Java Tutorial's [Collection Trail](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html).

Answer (score 4):

1. SortedSet or SortedMap, provided the keys are unique.
2. PriorityQueue.
3. Arrays.sort().
4. Own code.
5. A JDBC query with an ORDER BY clause.
6. An LDAP search against an indexed attribute.

I'm sure there are more.

Comment: This is actually an interesting answer (+1), but I am missing explanatory sentences or at least reference links. The question whether JDBC sorting happens in java is an interesting one, for example.

Comment: Do you think that attitude is helpful? A good developer should not only know his code but also be able to communicate what it does.

Comment: @EJP if you'd prefixed this comment with my name, I'd have seen it months ago. No, you didn't answer *my* question at all. We both answered swati's question.

Comment: @EJP so am I the one who wrote an "open-ended rant"? All I did was write that I thought your answer was good and that it would have been even better if you had provided some reference links. You are probably the first one on this site to take offense from a comment that literally attributes you (+1).

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyd: what you did is already written above and it exceeds that description considerably. Calling me unhelpful etc when I have already answered both the OP's question and the one you actually asked is futile and irritating. I don't consider references necessary for anything above. You do. We disagree.

Comment: @EJP We disagree. Let's leave it at that.

Answer (score 2):

1. Insertion Sort is used for small size  arrays.
2. Dual Pivot Quick Sort is used for larger size arrays.
3. MergeSort is used for sorting object.

Comment: Also, you can use a TreeMap to sort via a Red-Black Tree.

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays.sort(..)`, or implement sorting yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can stick your data into a `SortedSet` (e.g. `TreeSet`) and pull it out again in sorted order by traversing with an iterator. This is not really a general sorting method (since it doesn't allow duplicated entries), but would work for quite a lot of data set.